# How to compare the size of two directories?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to compare the total size of two directories `dir1` and `dir2` on different file-systems so that if `diff -r dir1 dir2` returns `0` then the total sizes will be equal. The `du` command returns the disk usage, and its option `--apparent-size` doesn't solve the problem. I now use something like

```
find dir1 ! -type d |xargs wc -c |tail -1
```

to know an approximation of dir1's size. Is there a better solution?

edit:
for example, I have (`diff -r dir1 dir2` returns 0: they are equal):

```
du -s dir1 --> 540
du -s dir2 --> 166

du -sb dir1 --> 250815 (the -b option is equivalent to --apparent-size -B1)
du -sb dir2 --> 71495

find dir1 ! -type d |xargs wc -c --> 62399
find dir2 ! -type d |xargs wc -c --> 62399
```

Comment: Why don't you use `du -s` to know the size of a directory?

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by "size of two directories".

Comment: @wok: it may report different sizes for two directories on different file-sytems even if the directories compare equal with `diff`.

Comment: @joschi: more or less the same as `du -s` but with the result being independant of the file-system where the directory is.

Comment: It would be interesting to see some data. Could you post a comparison for an example `dir1` and `dir2` showing `du -s`, `du --apparent-size` and your character counting script.

Comment: I suggest that your find commands seem to be telling you what you want to know.  You might be better off filtering on `-type f` so that you don't get waylaid by sockets, FIFOs, and other special devices.  But if the files compare equal with `diff -r dir1 dir2`, then you know that their sizes are equal because they hold the same stuff.  So, I think you have not yet got your goal clearly stated to yourself, and hence not to us, either.

Comment: @Jonathan: the problem I want to solve is for example to check that my assumption that dir1 and dir2 are equal *may* be true... if they are located on distant machines, the `diff` command (e.g. through ssh) can take much longer than two "finds".

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this question as copying large numbers of files between different platforms (esp. Windows and *NIX) can introduce subtle disparities under certain circumstances. (Unusually named files, restarting after a failure etc. are examples.) The chances of data going missing is much higher than the chance of data being bad so getting a sum size of the files in source and destination is usually good enough, and much faster than a byte-wise compare.

Answer (score 12):

i can't know what you want clearly. Maybe you want this?
`diff <(du -sh dir1) <(du -sh dir2)`

Comment: Maybe not, but it was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: This is not reliable, because `du -sh` can return different result for "visibly" (file by file) equal directories. For example, the `.` element can contain not 0 size which includes to the whole directory size.

Answer (score 4):

If your version of `find` has `-printf` you may find this to be quite a bit faster.

```
find dir1 ! -type d -printf "%s\n" | awk '{sum += $1} END{print sum}'
```

There are at least two ways to avoid scientific notation for outputting large numbers in AWK.

```
END {OFMT = "%.0f"; print sum}

END {printf "%.0f\n", sum}
```

The `.0` truncates the decimal places since we're really dealing with an integer and gawk's `%d` seems to incorrectly act like `%g` in version 3.1.5 (but not 3.1.6 and later).

However, from the `gawk` documentation:

> NOTE: When using the integer format-control letters for values
>        that are outside the range of the widest C integer type, 'gawk'
>        switches to the '%g' format specifier.

Beware of exceeding the maximum integer for your system/version of AWK.

Comment: I tried this and got an imprecise result: 2.11437e+11. Awk has a printf function so I tried: `find dir1 ! -type d -printf "%s\n" | awk '{sum += $1} END{printf "%f\n", sum}'` and I think it got a precise result: 211436502457.000000. Edit your answer and I'll definitely +1!

Comment: @JMcF: What version of AWK are you using? I edited my answer to add a little more information.

Comment: It's mawk 1.3.3 which comes with Ubuntu 12.04. It's the 64-bit version so these numbers should be well within range. Nevertheless, a very thorough answer, thanks.