# comparing folder size in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

```
actual_size="du -h $some_folder";   
y='eval $actual_size`
max_size=2MB

    if [[ y -lt  $max_size ]]; then            
            echo `du -h $some_folder`
            cp "$file" $some_folder` #$file points to some file
```

Whats wrong with above lines of code? I also tried

if [[ $(stat -c %s $some_folder) -lt  $max_size ]]; then

any help would be appreciated, Thnaks!

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You need to read a shell scripting tutorial, so you learn the proper syntax to assign the result of a command to a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare the size of two directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769206/how-to-compare-the-size-of-two-directories)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use POSIX `du` in a script it helps to have a wrapper function which only prints the output of its second to last field. This can be accomplished with `awk`, or here is how I do it using  `eval` to expand the second to last argument to a function:

```
#!/bin/sh 

duprint()
{
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
    then    printf "%s" $( eval printf '$'$(( $# - 1 )))
    fi
}

duwrap()
{
    duprint $(du -s $@ 2>/dev/null)
}

duwrap "$@"
```

This is useful for instance if you want the total size of several directories in anticipation of copying them over to a new filesystem:

```
./duwrapper /bin /etc /lib /boot
```

Finally, one can use their `du` wrapper function to compare directory sizes:

```
if [ "$(duwrap /lib)" -gt "$(duwrap /bin)" ]
then echo "/lib is greater"
fi
```